# How to access XACML policy from WSO2IS in API using WSO2API manager(How to create APIs using WSO2APIM to access XACML policy)

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-appm, wso2-identity-server

I have created XACML Policy having define multiple roles with different resources in WSO2IS. Now i want to know how to access XACML policy in my web application. How to create APIs using WSO2API Manager to access XACML policy.

```
    <!-- <Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"  PolicyId="TestPolicy2" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:first-applicable" Version="1.0">
<Target>
</Target>
<Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="Rule-1">
<Condition>
<Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:and">
<Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:and">
<Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-set-equals">
<Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-bag">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">building1</AttributeValue>
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">company1</AttributeValue>
</Apply>
<AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true">
</AttributeDesignator>
</Apply>
<Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-at-least-one-member-of">
<Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-bag">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
</Apply>
<AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true">
</AttributeDesignator>
</Apply>
</Apply>
<Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:any-of">
<Function FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
</Function>
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">admin</AttributeValue>
<AttributeDesignator AttributeId="http://wso2.org/claims/role" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true">
</AttributeDesignator>
</Apply>
</Apply>
</Condition>
</Rule>
<Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="Rule-2">
<Condition>
<Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:and">
<Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:and">
<Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-set-equals">
<Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-bag">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">building1</AttributeValue>
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">company2</AttributeValue>
</Apply>
<AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true">
</AttributeDesignator>
</Apply>
<Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-at-least-one-member-of">
<Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-bag">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">update</AttributeValue>
</Apply>
<AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true">
</AttributeDesignator>
</Apply>
</Apply>
<Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:any-of">
<Function FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
</Function>
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Physician</AttributeValue>
<AttributeDesignator AttributeId="http://wso2.org/claims/role" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true">
</AttributeDesignator>
</Apply>
</Apply>
</Condition>
</Rule>
<Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="Rule-3">
<Condition>
<Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:and">
<Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:and">
<Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-set-equals">
<Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-bag">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">building2</AttributeValue>
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">company3</AttributeValue>
</Apply>
<AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true">
</AttributeDesignator>
</Apply>
<Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-at-least-one-member-of">
<Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-bag">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">delete</AttributeValue>
</Apply>
<AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true">
</AttributeDesignator>
</Apply>
</Apply>
<Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:any-of">
<Function FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
</Function>
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Administrator</AttributeValue>
<AttributeDesignator AttributeId="http://wso2.org/claims/role" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true">
</AttributeDesignator>
</Apply>
</Apply>
</Condition>
</Rule>
<Rule Effect="Deny" RuleId="Deny-Rule">
</Rule>
</Policy>
           -->
```

This is my XACML policy which i want to access in APIs using WSO2 API manager to create api. How to create APIs using WSO2API manager  to access XACML policy.

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to publish your policy in WSO2 Identity Server and configure WSO2 APIM to validate the incoming authentication requests with IS acting as the entitlement server. You can refer this [doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/Enabling+Role-Based+Access+Control+Using+XACML) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for reply. In API publisher first step(Design) is am not getting properly. That part is not mention properly.

Comment: What is the APIM version you are using? Do you get any errors?

Comment: using wso2am-2.5.0. But in API publisher first step(Design) is not define there in documentation whcih link you suggested. that's am confusing what should i have to do in first step(Design)

Comment: One more thing when configure wso2am with wso2is using ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager. when we create users and roles with some permissions in wso2is. Those users and roles get display in wso2am but selected permission doesn't display in wso2am.